# In a mysql UNION can I exclude rows from the left part in the right part

Tags: mysql, union, except

I have a table where I store records for either a person or a group.

```
|id|entity_id|person_id|group_id|
|1 |000000001|999999999|NULL    |
|2 |000000001|NULL     |88888888|
|3 |000000002|999999999|NULL    |
|4 |000000003|NULL     |88888888|
```

How can I get all the records for person_id 999999999 and group_id 88888888, but the latter only when I do not have a record with entity_id 000000001 for person_id 999999999

So my result should be

```
|id|entity_id|person_id|group_id|
|1 |000000001|999999999|NULL    |
|3 |000000002|999999999|NULL    |
|4 |000000003|NULL     |88888888|
```

I am hoping this is possible in one query, but UNION, EXCEPT do not seem to do the trick.

I was trying something like

```
SELECT *
from myTable m1
WHERE NOT IS NULL person_id
UNION ALL
SELECT *
from myTable m2
WHERE NOT IS NULL group_id
EXCEPT (SELECT entity_id FROM m1)
```

but apparently mysql doesn't support EXCEPT

Comment: If it was me, I'd consider only storing group_ids, and requiring every person to be a member of a group (even if it was a group of 1)

Comment: @strawberry person is always member of a group, but the entry for the person overrides the entry for the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.person_id = '999999999'
   OR (
     t1.group_id = '88888888' 
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id AND t2.person_id = '999999999')
   )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e457b91c30a3630ed95b7b459b387b9e).